# What does InvalidArgumentError in tensorflow 2 mean?

Tags: python-3.6, tensorflow2.0

I am new tensorflow. I am trying to implement Linear Regression with custom training, following this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_training).

But when I try to compute `W*x + b`
I am getting this error

```
tf.add(tf.matmul(W,x),b)
```

> InvalidArgumentError: cannot compute Add as input #1(zero-based) was expected to be a double tensor but is a float tensor [Op:Add]

I initialized W and b

`W = tf.Variable(np.random.rand(1,9))`

`b = tf.Variable([1],dtype = tf.float32)`

`x = tf.Variable(np.random.rand(9,100))`

But when I changed the initialisation of b to

`b = tf.Variable(np.random.rand(1))`

I did not get any error. What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `np.random.rand(1,9)` (and other initializations) is of type `np.float64`. Using this with `tf.Variable` gives a tensor of type `tf.float64`.

The parameters to Tensorflow's `add` must be of the same type. The result of `matmul` is of type `tf.float64` and `b` is of type `tf.float32`. You need to cast one to the other's type.

In Tensorflow, you can either do this (recommended, going by convention):

```
# Can be done in a single line too
matmul_result = tf.matmul(W,x)
matmul_result = tf.cast(matmul_result, tf.float32)
tf.add(matmul_result, b)
```

Or you can do this:

```
tf.add(tf.matmul(W,x), tf.cast(b, tf.float64))
```

You can also directy change the type of numpy's array:

```
W = tf.Variable(np.random.rand(1,9).astype(np.float32))
```

Comment: So in tensorflow inorder to carryout mathematical operation the tensors type should be same. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: In most cases, yes. For exact details, refer to the tensorflow documentation on the functions you use.