# InvalidArgumentError: cannot compute Sub as input #1(zero-based) was expected to be a uint8 tensor but is a float tensor [Op:Sub]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

## Question

Please help understand the cause of the error and how to resolve.

#### Code

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

fashion_mnist = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = fashion_mnist.load_data()
x_full = np.concatenate((x_train, x_test), axis=0)

layer = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Normalization()
layer.adapt(x_full)
layer(x_train)
```

#### Error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-699c47b6db55> in <module>
----> 1 ds = layer(x_train)

~/conda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    966           with base_layer_utils.autocast_context_manager(
    967               self._compute_dtype):
--> 968             outputs = self.call(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    969           self._handle_activity_regularization(inputs, outputs)
    970           self._set_mask_metadata(inputs, outputs, input_masks)

~/conda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/preprocessing/normalization.py in call(self, inputs)
    109     mean = array_ops.reshape(self.mean, self._broadcast_shape)
    110     variance = array_ops.reshape(self.variance, self._broadcast_shape)
--> 111     return (inputs - mean) / math_ops.sqrt(variance)
    112 
    113   def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):

~/conda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py in binary_op_wrapper(x, y)
    982     with ops.name_scope(None, op_name, [x, y]) as name:
    983       if isinstance(x, ops.Tensor) and isinstance(y, ops.Tensor):
--> 984         return func(x, y, name=name)
    985       elif not isinstance(y, sparse_tensor.SparseTensor):
    986         try:

~/conda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py in sub(x, y, name)
  10098         pass  # Add nodes to the TensorFlow graph.
  10099     except _core._NotOkStatusException as e:
> 10100       _ops.raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
  10101   # Add nodes to the TensorFlow graph.
  10102   _, _, _op, _outputs = _op_def_library._apply_op_helper(

~/conda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
   6651   message = e.message + (" name: " + name if name is not None else "")
   6652   # pylint: disable=protected-access
-> 6653   six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
   6654   # pylint: enable=protected-access
   6655 

~/conda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

InvalidArgumentError: cannot compute Sub as input #1(zero-based) was expected to be a uint8 tensor but is a float tensor [Op:Sub]
```

#### Attempts

Tried dtype arg but same error.

```
layer = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Normalization(dtype='float32')
```

Divide by 1.0 fixed the issue but not sure the original cause.

```
x_full = np.concatenate((x_train, x_test), axis=0) / 1.0
x_train = x_train / 1.0
```

Does Keras only works with float32?

## Related issues

- [What does InvalidArgumentError in tensorflow 2 mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62244261/what-does-invalidargumenterror-in-tensorflow-2-mean)
- [InvalidArgumentError: cannot compute MatMul as input #0(zero-based) was expected to be a float tensor but is a double tensor [Op:MatMul]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54255431/invalidargumenterror-cannot-compute-matmul-as-input-0zero-based-was-expected)

Answer (score 5):

The cause is `preprocessing.Normalization` expect `float32` but your data was `uint8` and thus that error.

It's actually Tensorflow's problem not Keras itself as this is faster computation.

Reminder: float and int compute in different places in the processor and each processor have different performance on different data types, for example nvidia's gpus are faster with `float32` than `float16` while arm cpus are faster with the 16.

Pytorch too need two variables to be same data type or it won't work.

Divide an integer with a float in python automatically give you a new float, `x_train = x_train / 1.0` will make `x_train` `float32` (or `float64` or `float16` depending on what you have in `~/.keras/keras.json` but you have `float32` here).